# fullcalendar angular not showing events from server

Tags: angular, fullcalendar

i managed to get the events on the web console(added to static json file in testing with), the event that are implemented statically are shown in the calender, but the ones from the server are not, adding events works, when adding events they are saved in the database so i did not include any working services

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {

  @ViewChild('fullcalendar', { static: true }) fullcalendar!: ElementRef;

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('AppComponent initialized');
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log('AppComponent view initialized');
    const fullCalendarElement = this.fullcalendar?.nativeElement;

    if (fullCalendarElement && fullCalendarElement.fullCalendar) {
      const calendarApi = new FullCalendar.Calendar(fullCalendarElement, {
        plugins: [dayGridPlugin, interactionPlugin, timeGridPlugin, listPlugin],
        // ... other options
      });

      calendarApi.render();

      if (calendarApi) {
        console.log('Calendar API:', calendarApi);
      } else {
        console.error('FullCalendar API is undefined');
      }
    } else {
      console.error('FullCalendar ElementRef or fullCalendar property is undefined');
    }
  }

  calendarVisible = true;
  calendarOptions: CalendarOptions = {
    plugins: [interactionPlugin, dayGridPlugin, timeGridPlugin, listPlugin],
    headerToolbar: {
      left: 'prev,next today',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay,listWeek'
    },
    initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
    initialEvents: INITIAL_EVENTS,
    weekends: true,
    editable: true,
    selectable: true,
    selectMirror: true,
    dayMaxEvents: true,
    select: this.handleDateSelect.bind(this),
    eventClick: this.handleEventClick.bind(this),
    eventsSet: this.loadEventsFromBackend.bind(this)
  };
  currentEvents: EventApi[] = [];

  constructor(private changeDetector: ChangeDetectorRef, private http: HttpClient) {}

  handleCalendarToggle() {
    this.calendarVisible = !this.calendarVisible;
  }

  handleWeekendsToggle() {
    this.calendarOptions = {
      ...this.calendarOptions,
      weekends: !this.calendarOptions.weekends,
    };
  }
  loadEventsFromBackend() {
    this.http.get<any[]>('http://localhost:8080/api/events/all').subscribe(data => {
      console.log('Backend Data:', data);

      const backendEvents: EventApi[] = data.map((event: ModuleInterfaceModule) => {
        return {
          id: event.id.toString(),
          title: event.title,
          start: parseISO(event.start),
          end: parseISO(event.end),
          backgroundColor: event.color,
          startStr: event.start,
          endStr: event.end,
          //other properties
        };
      });
      if (INITIAL_EVENTS.length < backendEvents.length) {
        for (let i = 0; i < backendEvents.length; i++) {
          let addevent: EventInput = { id: backendEvents[i].id, title: backendEvents[i].title, start: backendEvents[i].startStr, end: backendEvents[i].endStr, color: backendEvents[i].backgroundColor };
          INITIAL_EVENTS.push(addevent);
        }
      }

      console.log('test events', INITIAL_EVENTS);
      this.currentEvents = backendEvents;
      this.changeDetector.detectChanges();

      const calendarApi = this.fullcalendar?.nativeElement.fullCalendar;
      if (calendarApi) {
        console.log('Adding Event Source:', backendEvents);
        calendarApi.addEventSource(backendEvents);
      }
    });
  }  
}
```

the event that are  implemented statically:

```
const TODAY_STR = new Date().toISOString().replace(/T.*$/, ''); // YYYY-MM-DD of today
export let INITIAL_EVENTS: EventInput[] = [
  {
    id: createEventId(),
    title: 'All-day event',
    start: TODAY_STR
  },
  {
    id: createEventId(),
    title: 'Timed event',
    start: TODAY_STR + 'T00:00:00',
    end: TODAY_STR + 'T03:00:00'
  },
  {
    id: createEventId(),
    title: 'Timed event',
    start: TODAY_STR + 'T12:00:00',
    end: TODAY_STR + 'T15:00:00'
  },
  {
    id: createEventId(),
    title: 'Timed event',
    start: '2024-01-28' + 'T11:00:00',
    end: '2024-01-28' + 'T12:00:00',
    backgroundColor:'red',
    
  }
];
```

html file:

```
<full-calendar #fullcalendar *ngIf="calendarVisible" [options]="calendarOptions">
      <ng-template #eventContent let-arg>
        <b></b>
        <i>{{ arg.event.title }}</i>
      </ng-template>
    </full-calendar>
```

ModuleInterfaceModule entity:

```
export class ModuleInterfaceModule {
    id!: number;
    title!: string;
    start!: string;
    end!: string;
    color!: string;
  }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gzVq5.png)

Answer (score 1):

if anyone had the same problem and is interested with solution, Instead of updating the INITIAL_EVENTS,  array directly, i tried updating the events using the FullCalendar API after fetching the events from the backend, code:

```
    export class AppComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
      @ViewChild('fullCalendar') fullCalendar!: FullCalendarComponent;
      calendarVisible = true;
      initialEvents: EventInput[] = [];
      calendarOptions: CalendarOptions = {
        plugins: [
          interactionPlugin,
          dayGridPlugin,
          timeGridPlugin,
          listPlugin,
        ],
        headerToolbar: {
          left: 'prev,next today',
          center: 'title',
          right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay,listWeek'
        },
        initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
        initialEvents: this.initialEvents,
        weekends: true,
        editable: true,
        selectable: true,
        selectMirror: true,
        dayMaxEvents: true,
        select: this.handleDateSelect.bind(this),
        eventClick: this.handleEventClick.bind(this),
        eventsSet: this.handleEvents.bind(this),
      };
      currentEvents: EventApi[] = [];
      private calendarApi: Calendar | null = null;
    
      constructor(private changeDetector: ChangeDetectorRef, private http: HttpClient) {}
    
      ngOnInit() {
        this.loadEventsFromBackend();
      }
    
      ngAfterViewInit() {
        if (this.fullCalendar) {
          this.calendarApi = this.fullCalendar.getApi();
          console.log('Calendar API initialized:', this.calendarApi);
        } else {
          console.error('FullCalendar component not found.');
        }
      }
    
      loadEventsFromBackend() {
        this.http.get<any[]>('http://localhost:8080/api/events/all').subscribe(
          (backendEvents) => {
            const newEvents = backendEvents.map((backendEvent) => ({
              id: backendEvent.id.toString(),
              title: backendEvent.title,
              start: backendEvent.start,
              end: backendEvent.end,
              color: backendEvent.color
            }));
      
            if (this.calendarApi) {
              this.calendarApi.removeAllEvents();
              this.calendarApi.addEventSource(newEvents);
              this.calendarApi.refetchEvents();
            }
      
            this.changeDetector.detectChanges();
          },
          (error) => {
            console.error('Error fetching events from the backend', error);
          }
        );
      }
     handleEvents(events: EventApi[]) {
        this.currentEvents = events;
        this.changeDetector.detectChanges();
      }
```